# Connect NodeJS client toAWS IoT through MQTT

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I'm trying to use NodeJS to connect my Raspberry Pi to AWS IoT and send some MQTT message. I am using the `aws-iot-device-sdk` library and this is actually my test code

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: '../certs/*******-private.pem.key',
    certPath: '../certs/*******-certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: '../certs/root-ca-certification.pem',
    clientId: 'provola',
    host: '*******-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
});

device.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connect');
    device.subscribe('topic_1');
    device.publish('topic_2', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1 }));
});

device.on('message', function (topic, payload) {
    console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
});
```

But when I run it, the only thing I get is the message `connect` printed continuously.
I tried to run the same code even on my laptop but I get the same result.

Moreover I would like to know where to get the CA certificate for the `caPath` parameter, because actually I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: As an Italian, I really like the clientId :D BTW listen to 'offline' and 'error' events on the device, it probably keeps getting disconnected and then connected again

Comment: Ahahah thank you, I forgot to change it before posting it XD Anyway, I will follow your suggestion and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Okay I tried to `console.log` something in the `device.on('error')` and so what I get is a continuous switching between the  `device.on('connect') ` and `device.on('error')`. Which could be the reason?

Comment: Okay I figured out what the problem was. In my policy document I have set `"action": "iot:Connect"` instead of `"iot:*"`. By changing it, now I'm able to publish and subscribe to topics.